# C# Generics, Abstract Classes, and Bounded Wildcards

Tags: c#, generics

I have a little problem when it comes to making Generics work in C#:

I have the following class:

```
public abstract class OphControl<TDataModel> : Control 
    where TDataModel : OphDataModel, new()
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The data model for this control.
    /// </summary>
    public TDataModel DataModel { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<OphControl<OphDataModel>> OphControls {
        get {
            return Controls.Cast<Control>().Where(control => control is OphControl<OphDataModel>).Cast<OphControl<OphDataModel>>();
        }
    }

    protected OphControl() {
        DataModel = new TDataModel();
    }
}
```

My problem is, that the `OphControls` property won't compile, because `OphDataModel` is abstract, and therefore I suppose it cannot be sure at compile-time that OphDataModel has a zero-args public constructor (notice the `new()` constraint on `TDataModel`).

I'm not even sure if this is the right way to go about it. What I *really* want is something like `OphControl<? extends OphDataModel>` from Java. I tried adding `out` to my `TDataModel` in the class declaration, but it tells me only delegates and interfaces can have covariant type parameters.

So how do I get around this pickle?

Comment: What is the exact error you get?  Pretty sure it's not related to `new`

Comment: Where is the declaration of `Controls`?

Comment: @JaredPar 'WinformToolkit.DataModels.OphDataModel' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'TDataModel' in the generic type or method 'WinformToolkit.OphControl<TDataModel>'

Comment: @ivowiblo It's a standard property of `Control`.

Comment: And what's the compilation error you get? It looks like it should work

Comment: Do you want OphControls to return all OphControls of any OphDataModel?

Comment: @DavidN Because that implies that all `OphControls` returned from that property have a `TDataModel` of the same type as the object `OphControls` is being accessed from (I think!)

Comment: @DavidN Because he wants that query to return items that implement `OphDataModel` but not `TDataModel`.  He wants that query to return all `OphControl` objects, not just those with the same generic argument as the "current" object.

Comment: Even if you remove the `new` constraint (and don't try creating a model) you'll still have the issue that it appears this code is intended to be covariant, but, being an abstract class instead of an interface, this type is not covariant with respect to its generic argument, so you'll have *that* hurdle to get over too.

Comment: @Servy Right, I see. I might try making it implement an interface with a covariant type parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few things of confusion. First, `OphControl<TDataModel>` does not derive from `OphControl<OphDataModel>` and you are correct about the `out` keyword (covariance/contravariance), they can only be used with delegates and interfaces. Since it is not a base class, you may not be able to cast it.

Unlike java, c# does not support generic wildcards (`...<? extends ...>`). The work around is to create a non-generic version and make it the base class.

```
public abstract class OphControl : Control { ... }

public abstract class OphControl<TDataModel> : OphControl 
    where TDataModel : OphDataModel, new() { ... }
```

Unfortunately, the base class cannot have the DataModel property because c# does not support covariant return types either.

At least you can have

```
public IEnumerable<OphControl> OphControls {
    get {
        return Controls.OfType<OphControl>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing you just need to change the generic parameter on `OphControls`:

```
public IEnumerable<OphControl<TDataModel>> OphControls {
    get {
        return Controls.Cast<Control>().Where(control => control is OphControl<TDataModel>).Cast<OphControl<TDataModel>>();
    }
}
```

This should *compile*, but without knowing more about your classes it's hard to say if this is *right*

Comment: Hi D Stanley; thanks for your answer - but I don't think that would be **right**... OphControls will return an enumeration of all child controls that are subclassed from OphControl - they will not all share the same OphDataModel type.